# performance between define variable global and initialize regularly

Tags: php

As the title of the article, I'm not sure which is faster and more optimal. Can someone help?

My Example:

bootstrap.php

```
$query = new Query();
```

file1.php

```
include bootstrap.php;
$query->where('a = b')->get('table');
```

file2.php

```
include bootstrap.php;
$query->where('a = b')->get('table');
```

**OR Measure 2**

bootstrap.php

```
function query() {
  return new Query();
}
```

file1.php

```
include bootstrap.php;
query()->where('a = b')->get('table');
```

file2.php

```
include bootstrap.php;
query()->where('a = b')->get('table');
```

Currently, I am prioritizing the second method because it supports code prompts better.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far to measure the speed? 
Why would you use a method to initialize an object, which has nothing it it's constructor?

Comment: @CalamityJane hi bro, i'm use a function to initialize an object becase it support IntelliSense good, use an variable global, it is IntelliSense not working better